# Create pagination from groupBy in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, pagination

```
$payments = Payment::with('borrowerUser','collectorUser')
    ->get()          
    ->groupBy('date_paid');
```

which gives me this result

[image]

My question is, is it possible for me to put a pagination in this scenario?

I already tried

```
$payments = Payment::listings()
    ->with('borrowerUser','collectorUser')
    ->groupBy('date_paid')->paginate(5);


and put {{$payments->listings()}} on my blade
```

but that doesn't work.

any suggestions? thank you in advance!

Comment: elaborate on "doesn't work" (means you have an expectation and it isn't being met, we don't know what that expectation is) .. the first code block you are calling `groupBy` on a Collection ... the second example you are calling `groupBy` on a query builder (part of the query) ... `$payments` is a collection, it is not the models inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this code in controller:

```
$payments = Payment::with('borrowerUser','collectorUser')
                ->groupBy('date_paid')->paginate(5);
```

put below code in blade file after for loop is completed

```
{!! $payments ->render() !!}
```

Comment: I think this is answer but it gives me this error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'aftscredit-appzcoder.payments.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `payments` group by `date_paid` limit 5 offset 0)` i guess there's a problem with my query

Answer (score 0):

This is the must read content from the laravel documentation

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot
>   be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with
>   a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database
>   and create a paginator manually.

[Documentation link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination)

You can use `orderBy` clause after `groupBy` to get the result, but still it won't give you efficient results